# How to make a common class for Gson deserializing

Tags: gson

Having a json,

```
{
  "owner": {
  "name": "frank",
  "address": "some street",
  "city": "a city"
  },
  "employees": [
    {
      "name": "todd",
      "address": "some street2",
      "city": "a city2",
      "title": "manager"
    },
    {
      "name": "micheal",
      "address": "some street3",
      "city": "a city3",
      "title": "engineer"
    }
  ],
  "partner": {
    "name": "ford",
    "address": "some street a",
    "city": "Magdeburg",
    "employees": [
      {
        "name": "marina",
        "address": "some street2",
        "city": "a city2",
        "title": "sectary"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

using POJO tool to get the data model for deserializing to classes, 
and see there at least

```
"name", "address", "city"
```

are common in the json objects.

question:  how to make a common clase Person(val name:String, val address:String, val city: String) to used in the data model for Gson to deserializing?

```
@ApiSerializable
@Parcelize
data class Owner(
  @SerializedName("name")
  val name: String? = null,
  @SerializedName("address")
  val address: String? = null,
  @SerializedName("city")
  val city: String? = null
) : Parcelable

@ApiSerializable
@Parcelize
data class Employee(
  @SerializedName("name")
  val name: String? = null,
  @SerializedName("address")
  val address: String? = null,
  @SerializedName("city")
  val city: String? = null,
  @SerializedName("title")
  val title: String? = null

) : Parcelable

@ApiSerializable
@Parcelize
data class employees(
  @SerializedName("employees")
  val employees: List<Employee>? = null
) : Parcelable

@ApiSerializable
@Parcelize
data class Partner(
  @SerializedName("name")
  val name: String? = null,
  @SerializedName("address")
  val address: String? = null,
  @SerializedName("city")
  val city: String? = null,
  @SerializedName("employees")
  val employees: List<Employee>? = null
) : Parcelable
```

Answer (score 0):

Fields which are common can be extracted in a superclass then extend that class wherever required.

Here is how i have implemented:

```
File file = new File("user_data.json");
System.out.println("file exists : " + file.exists());
JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(file));
final Gson gson = new Gson();
OwnerPartnerWrapper ownerPartnerWrapper = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, OwnerPartnerWrapper.class);
System.out.println(ownerPartnerWrapper.getOwner());
System.out.println("Converted Back to JSON");
System.out.println(gson.toJson(ownerPartnerWrapper));
```

POJO Classes

```
class OwnerPartnerWrapper {
        User owner;
        List<Employee> employees;
        Partner partner;

        public User getOwner() {
            return owner;
        }

        public void setOwner(User owner) {
            this.owner = owner;
        }

        public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
            return employees;
        }

        public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
            this.employees = employees;
        }

        public Partner getPartner() {
            return partner;
        }

        public void setPartner(Partner partner) {
            this.partner = partner;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "OwnerPartnerWrapper{" +
                    "owner=" + owner +
                    ", employees=" + employees +
                    ", partner=" + partner +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    class User {
        String name;
        String address;
        String city;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public String getCityclass OwnerPartnerWrapper {
        User owner;
        List<Employee> employees;
        Partner partner;

        public User getOwner() {
            return owner;
        }

        public void setOwner(User owner) {
            this.owner = owner;
        }

        public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
            return employees;
        }

        public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
            this.employees = employees;
        }

        public Partner getPartner() {
            return partner;
        }

        public void setPartner(Partner partner) {
            this.partner = partner;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "OwnerPartnerWrapper{" +
                    "owner=" + owner +
                    ", employees=" + employees +
                    ", partner=" + partner +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    class User {
        String name;
        String address;
        String city;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "User{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                    ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }


    class Owner extends User {

    }

    class Employee extends User {
        String title;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Employee{" +
                    "title='" + title + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    class Partner extends User {
        List<Employee> employees;

        public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
            return employees;
        }

        public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
            this.employees = employees;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Partner{" +
                    "employees=" + employees +
                    '}';
        }
    }() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "User{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                    ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }


    class Owner extends User {

    }

    class Employee extends User {
        String title;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Employee{" +
                    "title='" + title + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    class Partner extends User {
        List<Employee> employees;

        public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
            return employees;
        }

        public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
            this.employees = employees;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Partner{" +
                    "employees=" + employees +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```